# MYSQL Join 3 Tables - Using Result of Second Join for Third Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

Table Name: Anime

Table Fields: id, name, description, score, etc.

Ex. 1, SAO, A very detailed description, 7.5, etc.

-

Table Name: Genres

Table Fields: id, name

Ex. 1, Action

-

Table Name: Anime_Genres

Table Fields: id, anime_id, genre_id

Ex. 1, 1, 1 (anime_id is the primary key of Anime table, genre_id is primary key of Genre table)

-

I am trying to have a query that gets all of the information out of Anime and also gets me the genre names of the anime.

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.*, g.genres FROM anime as a
INNER JOIN (SELECT anime_id, GROUP_CONCAT(genre_id) as genres FROM anime_genres GROUP BY anime_id) as g ON a.id = g.anime_id
```

Which gets me the anime information and also all of the Genres primary ids, but I don't have their names.

I came up with this:

```
SELECT a_g.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT name FROM genres AS g WHERE g.id = a_g.genre_id)) as genre_names
FROM anime_genres as a_g
WHERE a_g.anime_id = 1
```

and was able to get the genre names from the ids.

What I can't figure out is how to basically combine these two queries (not literally, but results) into one query. I want to be able to turn the "genres" result from the first query into a list of the genre names, instead of the ids.

The closest I've gotten has been this:

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM genres as g WHERE g.id IN ((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(genre_id) FROM anime_genres as a_g WHERE a.id = a_g.anime_id))) as genres
FROM anime as a
WHERE a.id = 1
```

Which returns the results, but the "genre" column only returns the first genre name, not all of them. Also, through my searching I've read that a subquery inside WHERE IN can be slow?

I've been researching, but maybe I'm not going about this the right way.

Incidentally, "Anime" is a tv show, so it can have multiple genres, one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT a.*,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(g.name)
        FROM anime_genres ag JOIN
             genres g
             ON g.id = ag.genre_id)
        WHERE ag.anime_id = a.id
       ) as genre_names
FROM anime a;
```

Basically, you seem to want a `JOIN` in the subquery, as well as a correlation clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple join to do that and a `GROUP BY`  to get genre names.

```
SELECT a.*,  GROUP_CONCAT(g.name) genre_names
FROM anime a
INNER JOIN anime_genres ag ON a.id = ag.anime_id
INNER JOIN genres g ON g.id = ag.genre_id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: This works great as well! I accepted Gordon's answer since he answered a while ago and I'm just now getting to this, but thank you, your answer definitely furthered my understanding as well as Gordon's!

Comment: Not an issue, you can accept whichever suits you best. Happy to help.:)